# Suppose u and v are vertices in G. ecc(u)=m, ecc(v)=n, and m<n. prove d(u,v) is greater than or equal to n-m

Tags: graph-theory

I'm having trouble making progress on this. I'm trying to use contradiction and I'm really not seeing anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Ok lets recall the definition of ecc:

$$ecc(u)=\max_v d(u,v)$$

and the triangular inequality:

$$\forall u,v,w, d(u,v)\leq d(u,w)+d(w,v)$$

If you want to do it by contraduction assume that $d(u,v)<n-m$ and consider the vertex $w$ such that $d(v,w)=ecc(v)$ (it exists by definition).

Does that help you?